# Read a file if it hasn't read before in R

Tags: r, csv, if-statement, dataframe

I am writing an R script (not a function, just a collection of commands) that will read a csv file into a data frame. The CSV file is large and I don't want to read it every time I am running the script, if it has been already read. This is how I am checking if the variable exists:

```
if (!exists("df")) {
    df <- read_csv(file = "./some_file.csv")
}
```

However, every time I run the script no matter whether `df` exists or not, the `read_csv` function runs.

what am I missing here? Should I specify where `df` data frame should be searched?

Edit: Here is a bit of context to what I am trying to achieve. Usually, when working I work interactively in R or Rstudio. If I am readying a file, I read it and then the data is in the GlobalEnvinronment and I play with my data. I was trying to put all my work in a script and add to it step by step. In the beginning of the script, I read this CSV file which is about 11MB and then start manipulating the data. However, as I add new lines to my script and I want to test them, I don't want to read the CSV file again. It is already read and the data frame is available in the Global environment. That was the the reason I put the call to `read_csv()` function inside an if statement.

The problem is despite variable existing in global environment, every time I run the script, the `read_csv()` function is run, as if the `if` statement is ignored.

Comment: Is df your real variable name?

Comment: Can you show a bit more of what you're doing?

Comment: It's weird - it works for me exactly as you are using it. Did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`df` is actually a function in the `stats` package which normally exists :-)

So basically, just choose a better variable name!

Comment: That was my first thought too. But wouldn't that mean it always exists, so the file never gets read?

Comment: My variable isn't actually names df. I just used df as a shorthand for data frame. And isn't it that variable and function namespaces are different from each other so you can have a function called c and a variable called c all at the same time?

Comment: You can have that, but `exists` by default searches in all namespaces. Are you sure there's not a typo somewhere in your variable names in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use the "where" and "environment" argument and then try.  These argument basically drive the exists command to look at this variable at what place/environment.

```
exists(x, where = -1, envir = , frame, mode = "any",
   inherits = TRUE)
```

Here x is variable name

Comment: I tried this, but still my intended goal is not happening. The thing is after I run my script for the first time and I check the value of `exists("df")` it returns TRUE.

Comment: Isn't that expected behaviour?

Comment: Heroka, that is exactly what I don't understand. That is indeed the expected behaviour. However, if exists("df") returns TRUE, then the statement inside if shouldn't be run. But it runs regardless.